# trouble reading tokens in a file

Tags: c

i'm doing a homework assignment that requires reading from an input file. the program just exits with error, however, and i can't tell why. here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen( "input.txt", "r");
  FILE *outputF = fopen( "output.txt", "w");
  if( !fp || !outputF){
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open files for input/output");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  char line[250];
  double factor;
  int expo;

  while( fscanf( fp, "%f%d", factor, expo) == 1){
    if( factor == 0){
       fprintf(outputF, "%s\n", "undefined");
    }
  else{
      double total = 1;
      for(int i = 0; i < expo; i++){
        total = total * factor;
      }
      fprintf(outputF, "%f", total);
  }
 }
 fclose(fp);
 fclose(outputF);

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

i'm thinking the problem is with the "while" line but i also tried it with the following code and it did not work. the input file has a doulbe and an int seperated by a space. i.e. "2.33 3"

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", line) == 1){
 char *token;
  token = strtok(line, " ");
  float factor;
  sscanf(token, "%f", &factor);
  token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
  int expo;
  sscanf(token, "%d", &expo);
```

Comment: First mistake `while (fscanf( fp, "%f%d", factor, expo) == 1)` has to be `while (fscanf( fp, "%f%d", factor, expo) == 2)` read `fscanf()`'s manual. It does not return a truth value it returns the number of matches parameters in the string. Second mistake, *undefined behavior* due to the incorrect `scanf()` format specifier, for `double` you need `"%lf"` and not `"%f"`.

Answer (score 0):

1. First problem `while (fscanf( fp, "%f%d", factor, expo) == 1)` has to be

   ```
   while (fscanf(fp, "%f%d", &factor, &expo) == 2)
   ```

   read `fscanf()`'s manual. It does not return a truth value it returns the number of matched specifiers in the string.
2. Second problem, *undefined behavior* due to the incorrect `scanf()` format specifier, for `double` you need `"%lf"` and not `"%f"`.
3. Third problem, you must pass the address of the values you want to read to allow `scanf()` to store the result in those variables, that's what the `&` are doing in the fixed `fscanf()` above.

---

**Note**: Your compiler should warn about two of these errers, the wrong format specifier and not using the `&` address of operator for these particular specifiers. There are two options, you are ignoring these warnings or you are compiling with warnings turned off. The first of these possible reasons is really bad, do not ignore warnings. The second, read the documentation for your compiler and enable as much diagnostics as possible to avoid silly mistakes.

Comment: thanks. I just compiled how code blocks came configured, other than changing  to c99. the while line still doesn't seem to work though, it always returns 0.0000 for the double and 42352830 for the exponent.